# My website does not work on iphone or mac

Tags: php, html, css

What happens is that I have a website on android that loads me correctly, on the desktop as well. But on iphone or mac os, I have problems and that is that it has many defects that is to say that it does not catch the styles.

I leave you part of the html and the css that I use in addition to the bootstrap 4 library.
They can also be viewed on my host to verify the problem of the iphone because at first glance on the desktop it looks normal, the problem is on an **Apple device**.

**https://arstrikestudio.com/dlx/**

HTML.

```
<div class="delexlp">
  <span class="ir-arriba"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
  <div id="logo-div" class="paddingleft">
    <div id="logo-img">
  <img id="lgefect" src="delexni/img/default/delex2020-01.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="imgscroll">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 oculto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="d-none d-md-block sectlp">
<img src="delexni/img/default/delex.svg" alt="">
  <br>
  <div class="container">
  <p class="text-center">Facilitamos a nuestros clientes el proceso<br>de comprar por internet brindandoles un servicio<br><span style="background-color:orange;color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SIMPLE, CONFIABLE Y RAPIDO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br>ganandonos su confianza libra por libra.</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="register">CREA TU CUENTA</a>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="login">INICIA SESION</a>
  </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sectlpm d-md-none">
          <div class="row spaceblank2" style="padding-left:18%">
          <img src="delexni/img/default/delex.svg" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding-top:40vh">
            <div class="container">
            <p class="text-center spaceblank">Facilitamos a nuestros clientes el proceso<br>de comprar por internet brindandoles un servicio<br><span style="background-color:orange;color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SIMPLE, CONFIABLE Y RAPIDO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br>ganandonos su confianza libra por libra.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding-left:15%">
            <div class="text-center">
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="register">CREA TU CUENTA</a>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="login">INICIA SESION</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block col-lg-6">
        <img src="delexni/img/default/delex-x.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS.

```
body{
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.delexlp{
background: url('../img/default/fondo2.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.delexlg{
background: url('../img/default/fondo.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
#logo-div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 14vh !important;
    width: 100vw;
}
#logo-div img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.black{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
}
.oculto{
  display: none;
}
.imgscroll{
  height: 6000px;
}
.textground{
  font-size: 720px;
}

.ir-arriba {
    display:block;
  text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:48px;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:20px;
    right:50%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 6;
}

.btn-delex{
  background-color: #f6871f;
  color: white;

}
.btn-delex2{
  background-color: #f6871f;
  color: white;

}
@keyframes crescendo {
  0%   {transform: scale(1);}
  100% {transform: scale(43);}
}

.paddingleft{
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.sectlp {
  padding: 15%;

}
.pdtop15{
  padding-top: 15%;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
.form-control{ background-color: red; }
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 ,h6{
  font-weight: 200;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

p, li, a{
  font-size: 14px;
}

fieldset{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

/* GRID */

.twelve { width: 100%; }
.eleven { width: 91.53%; }
.ten { width: 83.06%; }
.nine { width: 74.6%; }
.eight { width: 66.13%; }
.seven { width: 57.66%; }
.six { width: 49.2%; }
.five { width: 40.73%; }
.four { width: 32.26%; }
.three { width: 23.8%; }
.two { width: 15.33%; }
.one { width: 6.866%; }

/* COLUMNS */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1.6%;
}

.col:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}



.row{
  padding: 20px 0;
}

/* CLEARFIX */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

/* STEPS */

.steps{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: #fff;*/
  text-align: center;
}


.steps li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.steps li.is-active{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
}

/* FORM */

.form-wrapper .section{
  padding: 0px 20px 30px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 0);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  -moz-transform-origin: top center;
  -ms-transform-origin: top center;
  -o-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-wrapper .section h3{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-wrapper .section.is-active{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.form-wrapper .button, .form-wrapper .submit{
  background-color: #3498db;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.form-wrapper .submit{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="text"],
.form-wrapper input[type="password"],.form-wrapper input[type="email"],.form-wrapper input[type="number"]
,.form-wrapper select,.form-wrapper textarea{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;
  width: 50%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label:before{
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before{
  display: block;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label h4{
  margin: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
}

.form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label h4{
  color: #3498db;
}

.spaceblank{
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.89;
}
.spaceblank2{
  background-color: white;
}

.pd30{
  padding-top: 30%;
}
.pd60{
  padding-top: 60%;
}
.pd200{
  padding-top: 200%;
}

/* tabletas */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

}

/* escritorio normales */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 { font-size:px; }
}

/* pantallas grandes */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
/*****/
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .form-control { font-size: px; }
    .form-wrapper .section{
      position: absolute;
      min-height: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  .form-control { font-size: px; }

}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .form-control { font-size: 30px; }
    .form-wrapper input[type="text"],
    .form-wrapper input[type="password"],.form-wrapper input[type="email"],.form-wrapper input[type="number"]
    ,.form-wrapper select,.form-wrapper textarea{
      width: 100%;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 32px !important;
    }
    .form-wrapper .button{font-size: 32px !important;}
    .ocultar{
      display: none !important;
    }
    .form-wrapper .section{
      min-height: 30px;
      max-height: 100px
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a PHP error on that address.

Comment: @Niloct where?.

Comment: Browse the URL.

Comment: @Niloct ok, What kind of error did you find?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/u654312249/domains/arstrikestudio.com/public_html/dlx/models/conexion.php:7  (...)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mount the database

Comment: This is all, you can visit again.

Comment: Well the homepage seems normal. It zooms when clicking the arrow and shows the company info. Registering seems to work. I'm on a mac. Can you make a list of the errors you think are happening ?

Comment: Yes, most of all it is on Apple mobile devices. It looks very different from android.

List:
1- The page looks very different on iphone than on android.
2- I have another error and that is that I cannot get the image that is measured 1080x1920 for mobile to cover the entire screen, it remains a space in the lower part.

Basically on iphone I do not get all the css styles, but android if everything is normal.

Comment: Side note: you should fix your SSL certificate it has expired 65 days ago. Not a good thing for clients to see that.

Comment: Why are you embedding photos on svgs ?? Svg is supposed to be vector images not photos. You should export those to png files.

Comment: Regarding the certificate, don't worry, this is my test host. With the image yes, I am using vector images, but the cell phone image does not cover the entire screen of the phone. If I export the image to png, when doing the zoom effect it loses quality and looks pixelated, with teeth around the image for that reason I use SVG.

Comment: This is really a messy code. The only img that you stretch is the one in `#logo-img`, the background isn't stretched at all. The mobile version is broken in Android too (tested on my S9). The problem is that you rely on the middle part of the E logo to grow enough so to cover the entire height of the screen. It's a cool effect but your code is so messy I suggest you rewrite it from scratch. Don't just code anything to make the visual work.

Comment: I think your best bet is to take the logo part of the `delexni/img/default/Movil-01.svg` out of the svg, and trim it to have only the width and height of logo without background. Then you continue to put it as a `img` with svg source (because if you put it to a `background` indeed pixelation occurs), and center it on screen. Then I think it will be easier to zoom only the logo reliably.

Comment: I am working on a solution for your problem. I think until this evening (GMT-3) I will be able to post an answer.

Comment: well thank you very much

Comment: I'm still on it. Made it work on iOS. But I'm polishing it and need your help. Could you make a `Movil-01.svg` that's just the trimmed text in white, without the black background ? No 480x800, just the width/height necessary for the white logo, on an transparent background.

Comment: Well I did the most part of it. Check https://delex.imfast.io/ (this is a free website host) and https://github.com/niloct/delex_refactor . I am too tired to post an answer now, but you can see that all mobile zoom should work now. I've changed the scroll to be automatic when you touch the arrow. Except for a bug in mobile padding which fast.io is pesky catching the old version, the rest should work. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, before I started helping, I had already started working on fixing the code. From what I am provided I am very grateful to you just take a few CSS things which is the calculation of the space in "Black" of the image, the zoom effect leaves it like this, but add a part of your JS code that It helped me a lot and it is the method to add the 'transform-origin' and integrate it into my code that I already had.

Comment: Alright no problem. I've learned a few things doing this. When you are done with your questions please accept the answer. I'll keep the github repository on in case you want to browse it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the mobile version in all devices had problems in zoom, and I will explain how I fixed it.

First, when you `transform: scale();` an element, if the width/height of the zoom rate are the same, you can provide only 1 parameter instead of 2 (as in original code). Also, doing it using `jQuery.scroll()` is really slow on some devices.

But you were indeed spot on in your code when you created a scale in the `style` attribute of the element, instead of an animation. If you do an animation, it gets a blurred zoom effect on desktop, inclusive. Also, putting the pictures embedded on a svg indeed made better optimization than converting the images to png (really!).

Putting the animation on the style, only iOS makes some blurriness, which I failed to remove.

So the **main point** of the answer is the css rule [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Since each mobile device has a different screen size, simply zooming on center of image (which is the default behavior without `transform-origin`), makes the image zoom on the wrong spot.

SO, I got a specific coordinate of a working device which transform-origin worked, and applied a calculation to get the corresponding coordinates on each device (for instance, calculated using the `document.documentElement.clientHeight` for height). And then setting these coordinates on transform-origin it worked.

Also second important point: for the animation to behave performant on mobile, I've used [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

There is an important detail: you were totally correct in making a svg with black background and transparent letters. I've fiddled A LOT and the final answer made use of that, but I've trimmed the logo as I asked you, and made **black borders** calculated in css using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), to fill entire screen on mobile.

And finally, I've removed all superfluous paddings and applied [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on elements to get control of centering things vertically/horizontally.

You can see all my edits on https://github.com/niloct/delex_refactor, and I've published it using the **awesome** https://fast.io free hosting service integrated with github (on https://delex.imfast.io/).

Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am starting in programming. I would like you to recommend courses or places to learn best programming practices.

Comment: I found a neat website for training called Exercism: https://exercism.io/my/tracks/javascript, and google is your friend. Whenever you have a question, google "<keyword> mdn" (for your specific keyword) and see the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ reference. Also in exercism you can see other solutions to problems. Javascript track has more than 100 exercises. I am going through my Python track steadily.